# How to make comet long polling in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below is my ajax request made to server in interval. I would like to know how can I keep the request open while there's no data returned from server.

```
    (function newMessage(){
          jQuery.ajax({

           method: "POST",
           url:"/index.php",
           "data": data,
           error: function() {
             reject('error');
           },  
           success: function(result) {
             console.log(result);          
           }
       });
         setTimeout(function(){
            newMessage();
          }, 3000);
      })()
```

In the server side, I use usleep while no data is returned by server hoping that this request to the server will be kept open.But it still make other request keeping each request open.

```
 //request to server
    $results = $model->getNewMessages($id, $userId, $lastupdate);
        $counter = sizeof($results);

       while($counter == 0){
        usleep(10000); 
       }
```